# rm variable is not returning payment status if the transaction is success in paypal

Tags: php, paypal

Hi Iam new to paypal and php I have created a paynow button in paypal where user can only create the profile on my site once the payment id done.I used the following html form for it.

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@yahoo.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Legacy Finder">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount"  id="amount">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?=base_url()?>user/create_profile/success">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?=base_url()?>user/create_profile">
    <input type="image" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/images/paynow.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" style="margin-left:17px" >
    <img alt"" border="0" src="paynow.png" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I have tested by following cases

1) Provided business email address "test@yahoo.com".The transaction is successful but the results are getting as GET.Iam only getting the Transaction Id not the payment status.

2)Provided invalid business email address test1@yahoo.com.The trasaction is not success I can able to get the post values and payment status as pending.The following is the result of post

```
Array ( [transaction_subject] => [txn_type] => web_accept [payment_date] => 02:18:06 Apr 01, 2015 PDT [last_name] => testing [residence_country] => US [pending_reason] => unilateral [item_name] => Profile [payment_gross] => 219.95 [mc_currency] => USD [payment_type] => instant [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible [payer_status] => verified [verify_sign] => A0iri-xagdNJDeSvGm9wMkE8ysoFAJYtu-l80Ta2Gk0Rxnv5qs4gpim2 [tax] => 0.00 [test_ipn] => 1 [payer_email] => xyz2@gmail.com [txn_id] => 1MP57538MB029774W [quantity] => 1 [receiver_email] => test1@yahoo.com [first_name] => test [payer_id] => KZ6XDS2RSJUT6 [item_number] => [handling_amount] => 0.00 [payment_status] => Pending [shipping] => 0.00 [mc_gross] => 219.95 [custom] => [charset] => windows-1252 [notify_version] => 3.8 [auth] => Ak8996lOB.AEd9HRJHKoJBUUUfPRGpev0wO0mI2N-G9VDMJ18wwFT5nrk8-LE3Ztm5e-2qlLqJv22Zli4kjqJ3g )
```

**If the variable "rm" is set then we will get the result as post. why couldn't I able to get the same detailed info (i.e payment is success) when the transaction is success.**